# “user store” solution for a website

Tags: authentication, user-management, accounting

I want implement a website that providing too many services to end users like:
1- CMS service (I would like using DNN, Joomla, Wordpress, etc)
2- LMS service (I would like using open eLMS, DotNetScorm, etc)
3- Email Service (I would like using MS Exchange, etc)
4- Web storage service like "one drive" (I would like using a software that existing in the market like previous services)
5- And another services for providing to form of public ....

My strategy in this project, is using the existing software in the market. I don't want to development any software/application, I want only configuration of existing software to the one project.

For implement above services on my website, I should have a central "user store" solution that ability to integration of these services. In the other words, I want having a central "user store" for register, Authenticate and authorize users for providing above services to them.

Please offered me best solution of this scenario, about "user store".

Answer (score 1):

Its called SSO or single sign on. While I'm not a dev, I'm a very happy user [oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) (I use it to log in on this site). Dosen't seem quite perfect here cause of onedrive.

For corporate use, I've known of people tying things into [active directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) - there's plugins for various bits of software, like [wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/next-active-directory-integration/), though with the breadth of this question you'll need to look up plugins for your preferred solution for each software product, and/or write plugins yourself where it dosen't exist.

AD also needs windows server and licences though the 'important' parts seem to have open source implementations.

Comment: Hi Journeyman, Thank you for your reply. AD don't ability for using as a "User Store" for a public website [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3955d689-4bbd-4b93-8c14-0220b07e13b1/no-body-no-experience-i-need-a-web-portal-for-active-directory?forum=winserverDS). And I don't want SSO solution. I want a software that can give me "single point" for users management, like Active Directory in internally corporate network.

Comment: Active Directory can I believe.  I know that LDAP can - and AD is simply Microsofts implementation of that.  Write a few simple scripts - create ldap user, set ldap user password, let ldap user manage their own password.  Use AD/LDAP for authentication, and then let the other system determine what rights, roles, etc. that now-known user has.

Comment: Hi ivan, Thanks for reply. At first I choose AD for my project, but by [this discuss](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3955d689-4bbd-4b93-8c14-0220b07e13b1/no-body-no-experience-i-need-a-web-portal-for-active-directory?forum=winserverDS) I give up from it. Could you solve these challenges?